# How to change webkitSpeechRecognition's volume or sensitivity?

Tags: google-chrome, webkitspeechrecognition

I'm using Chrome's **[webkitSpeechRecognition](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API)** to interact with a bot.

If I say: **"play music"**, it's playing an `.mp3`. That's cool, but if I give it a command while the music is on (e.g.: **"stop music"**), the bot heard me and understood the sentence, but the function `isFinal` isn't triggered because the mic hears something (the song probably)(so the order is never executed).

**The question is:** How can I make it ignore the music sound? Set down the volume when I'm talking? why not :/ Searching about changing `webkitSpeechRecognition`'s sensitivity.

Do you know how?